# Tied by a string of fate - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Throw me down, I'll come right back up
>
> You and I are tied by a string of fate
>
> Cut me in half and you may greet a friend
>
> With your mom I play classical tunes

Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> a Yo-Yo

Throw me down, I'll come right back up

> That's what yo-yos do.

You and I are tied by a string of fate

> You are connected to the yo-yo by a string

Cut me in half and you may greet a friend

> Yo!

With your mom I play classical tunes

> Yo Yo Ma, famous cellist.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, well done!

Answer (score 1):

Who am I?

> Yo-yo

Throw me down, I'll come right back up

> You throw down a yo-yo and it comes back up.

You and I are tied by a string of fate

> You and the yo-yo are tied together by string.

Cut me in half and you may greet a friend

> You greet a friend by saying "Yo!".

With your mom I play classical tunes

> Yo-Yo Ma  is a Chinese-American cellist.